# Change key's value in array of objects with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am building a page that allows customers to change information, which is then passed to the admin team to verify before accepting. I am trying to keep the form dynamic in only passing information that was changed by the customer. I'm using the function below to create an array of objects:

```
$('input, textarea, select').change(function(){
    var key = $(this).attr('name');
    var obj = {};
    obj[key] = $(this).val();
    myArray.push(obj);
});
```

Which is working correctly, however today I noticed that when changing the field multiple times it created multiple objects with the same name.

My question is how can I find the key which is dynamic and change the value if it exists in the array?

I tried using:

```
$.each(myArray, function( key, value ) {
    console.log(key, value);
});
```

But this outputs the index and then the complete object, I need to find the key of the object and then change the value if it already exists.

Comment: Before pushing you have to check if the object exists in myArray. You could use Lodash's method findIndex

Comment: I posted an answer but I think I'm actually not understanding your question. Could you post an example of what you want your array of objects to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `myArray` is a array not a object, so the `key` is just the index of the object in the array.

To check if the object with the specific key exists,

```
function getObjWithKey(myArray, key){
   var retVal;
   $.each(myArray, function(index, obj) {
       if(key != undefined && obj[key]){
           retVal = obj;
           return false;
       }
   });
   return retVal;        
}
```

Comment: Thank you Z.Z, this actually answered my question but I realized the way I was doing this was pointless. I was creating an array then filling it with objects, then converting it to an object before passing it to PHP anyway. I have since just used an object to begin with and solved my issues. I appreciate everyone's help.